# Set attribute on class but not on instances

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

I'm creating some custom classes in Python and I was wondering if there was any way to define an attribute on a class without having all of its instances inherit the attribute.

For example:

```
class Foo():
    def bar():
        pass

Foo.bar # would return `bar` function
instanceOfFoo = Foo()
instanceOfFoo.bar # would raise an AttributeError
```

I know I could subclass `Foo`, override `bar`, and manually raise an `AttributeError` as a `@property` to give the "appearance" that `bar` doesn't exist, but is there any way to do this without subclasses?

Context: I'm trying to replicate the `Date` class from JavaScript, where calling `Date.parse` (on the `Date` class itself) will do something, but calling `parse` on a `Date` instance will not do anything because instances don't inherit the `parse` function from `Date`. (They inherit all their properties from `Date.prototype` which is why it works there.)

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a class method https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod or static method https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: @Klaus D. Classmethods though are still inherited by instances of the class. They just received the class as their first argument instead of an instance of the class. I'm looking for a way to prevent instances from inheriting a class's attribute altogether.

Comment: Well, you either inherit or not. In general trying to mimic one language in an other, very different language is a questionable thing.

Comment: There is no way to prevent your instances from inheriting the class methods. A possible "dirty" workaround could be that inside your function bar, you can check that you are getting an instance as first argument and then can raise AttributeError or inside your __init__ function you can remove that bar function attribute.

Comment: @Ankur Sharma Both of those are clever. How do I remove the attribute in the `__init__` though? It seems like methods are declared after the `__init__`. Using `del self.bar` raises an AttributeError because `bar` is inherited after the constructor is done executing. If I can't do the `__init__` route, I might go the first way.

Comment: @Klaus D. I know I probably shouldn't be trying to get aspects of one language into another but I was just double checking that someone in the SO community didn't know of some decorator or function or something from a library I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @ChristianFigueroa Inside __init__ instead of deleting that attribute, try initialising it with something (maybe something that raises an exception), which could be a common callable for all of your such cases. OR just to try you can set self.bar = None. This would work.

Comment: @Ankur Sharma Ah that might be what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for using metaclasses.

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class Foo(metaclasses=MetaFoo):
    pass

Foo.bar # returns `bar` method
instanceOfFoo = Foo()
instanceOfFoo.bar # raises AttributeError
```

`Foo` is being created using the `MetaFoo` class and is inheriting the `bar` method in the process. Since inheritance only works with direct instances of a class, `Foo` (an instance of `MetaFoo`) inherits the `bar` method, but `instanceOfFoo` (an instance of `Foo` but not `MetaFoo`) does not inherit the method.

Answer (score 1):

There is one work-around for your question. Note that in `python` You can't call `Foo.bar()`, unless `bar()` is declared either as `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = self.foo

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return 1

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        raise AttributeError("Method not implemented for instances of a class.")

print(Foo.bar()) # --> 1
t = Foo()
print(t.bar())   # --> AttributeError: Method not implemented for instances of a class.
```